# Prove that $B$ is invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix such that the rank of $A$ is $k$, also consider $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq m$ and $1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_k \leq n$ such that $\left\{A_{i_{1}\ast},A_{i_{2}\ast},\ldots, A_{i_{k}\ast}\right\}$ is linearly independent (these are the rows of matrix $A$) and $\left\{A_{\ast j_{1}},A_{\ast j_{2}},\ldots, A_{\ast j_{k}}\right\}$ is linearly independent (these are the columns of matrix $A$). Prove that the $k \times k$ matrix $B$ obtained by eliminating all rows except rows $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$ and eliminating all columns, except columns $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_k$ from $A$ is an invertible matrix.

**Proof:**

We have a matrix $A$ of size $m \times n$ with rank $k$. This means there are $k$ linearly independent rows or columns in the matrix. We are given a set of row indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ and a set of column indices $j_1, j_2, ..., j_k$, and we are told that the corresponding row vectors to indices $i$ and column vectors to indices $j$ are linearly independent.

Now, we are asked to prove that if we take the submatrix $B$ of $A$ consisting of the rows with indices $i$ and the columns with indices $j$, then this submatrix is invertible.

To prove this, we need to recall what it means for a matrix to be invertible. A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero. And the determinant of a matrix is zero if and only if the rows (or columns) of the matrix are linearly dependent.

Therefore, to prove that matrix $B$ is invertible, we need to prove that its rows (or columns) are linearly independent. But this has already been given to us in the problem statement: we are told that the row vectors corresponding to indices $i$ and column vectors corresponding to indices $j$ are linearly independent. Therefore, the rows and columns of matrix $B$ are linearly independent, which means its determinant is nonzero, so the matrix is invertible.

Is any error in this proof?

Comment: Your argument is not sufficient. Indeed, given a couple of linearly independent vectors, let's say $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(1, 0, 0)$, it is not true that they are still linearly independent if we remove elements from them (try to remove the third elements from both, and you will get $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$, which are not linearly independent).

Comment: Some suggest for finish? @the_candyman

Comment: suggestion: you can assume WLOG that the first $k$ columns of $A$ are the ones in your linearly independent set $\left\{A_{\ast j_{1}},A_{\ast j_{2}},\ldots, A_{\ast j_{k}}\right\}$... now show that there exists an invertible matrix $R$ such that $\big(AR\big)$ has the same first $k$ columns as $A$ and the rest of the columns are zero.  Finally, see what happens when you delete the relevant rows of $A$.